# Create own BibTeX style or customize existing one?

Tags: latex, coding-style, tex, bibtex, bibliography

I'm looking for a way to define new [BibTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX) style or to customize existing one. I have two reasons for this:

1. I want the author names/editors to be italic (for articles in book, book, magazines, encyclopedia etc)
2. I want numbers at the beginning

Example:

1. *Secondname, B*. Book title. Place Year. Site number.
2. *Article author, A*. Article title. In: *Book author, B*, Book title,
   Place Year, site number.

Any suggestions?

P.S.: The OS is [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used `latex makebst` to generate new one :)

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend [biblatex](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html). It's not included yet with most TeX distributions at the authors request, but it is completely usable and very well [documented](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). I think it will be less painful to use to get what you want, and also a better investment for the future as I think biblatex will quickly become the favored standard once it has it's 1.0 release.

Comment: @Charles - what does that mean? It exists as a package, is fully documented, fully functional and completely usable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) :

```
This is the custom-bib package for generating customized BibTeX bibliography
styles from a generic file by means of the docstrip program that is part of
the LaTeX2e installation.
```

Answer (score -1):

Find a standard bibtex stylesheet for your citation style: IEEE, ACM, MLA, specific journal, etc.

What style are you trying to conform to?